# How to get out of the Google Sandbox quickly?

Tags: seo, google-sandbox

My blog  has been penalized by Google and it remained in Google Sandbox until now. Unfortunately, I don't know hot to escape the Google penalty box. Please help me.

Comment: There is no such thing as a Google Sandbox. This was a myth from many years ago. You just need to revert whatever caused the penalty and then your rankings will be reinstated...

Answer (score 1):

If you've fixed all of the errors that caused the penalty, and Google is still not indexing your pages, you likely need to file a reconsideration request.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35843?hl=en